# c# wpf checkbox content from one list to another

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list where i dynamically store checkboxes(with grid content in it). Next to the list i have a button who,when clicked, must put the selected checkboxes with content in the right list. When delete from right list is clicked, the selected item(s) on the right side needs to be deleted.

How is this possible? Suppose i have this code:

```
  CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
  Grid panel= new Grid();
  panel.Width = 260;
  cbox.Content = panel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- Listbox.ItemTemplate to represent the data you want (so that it looks like CheckBox:Label)
- Use 2 ObservableCollections to store 2 lists that you have
- In your buttons you can bind to Current Item in the List it is associated with
- On button click, it will get current select Item and Add/Remove from ObservableCollections as needed

Let me know if you need specific details. The good thing about ObservableCollections is that whenever collection changes, anything bound to it (like ListBox) will get updated.

so that any manupilation with the data is outside View so to speak and done on ViewModel.